What’s the meaning of the "floating sheds"?

Boats rocked in the floating sheds of the yacht harbor.

Does "floating shed" refer to the cabin of the yacht?

You do get literally floating boat sheds, i.e. sheds which house boats and float on water, while floating has a variety of other meanings. It's impossible to be sure without more information.

Welcome to ELU. It’s a good idea not to accept the first answer that gets posted as soon as it’s posted because it doesn’t always prove to be the best answer.

Yes, I misunderstood it. Please unaccept my answer so I can delete it

And these floating sheds can also be moored to the shore.  https://i0.wp.com/richardsondocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/2014-dec15_boathouse.jpg

Thank you everyone.

They are slips or individual boat houses with shed roofs.

